# Method overloading with an object implementing two interface in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand what happen here :

```
    interface IA
    {
        void MethodA();
    }

    interface IB
    {
        void MethodB();
    }

    class AB : IA, IB
    {
        public void MethodA()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method A");
        }

        public void MethodB()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method B");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Test(IA a)
        {
            a.MethodA();
        }

        public void Test(IB b)
        {
            b.MethodB();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AB Ab = new AB();
            Test(Ab);
        }
    }
```

The output is "Method A".

The object "AB" implement both IA and IB, but for obscure reason, the compiler use the `void Test(IA a)`version of Test rather than the `void Test(IB b)`.

I thought it was because of the order of the interfaces implementation, but I changed the code to
`class AB : IB, IA` and the result is still the same.

Anyone have a clue of why ?

Comment: Make them both static.  Since one isn't it can only be called like `var p = new Program; p.Test(Ab);`.  Once you do that you'll get a compiler error about them being ambiguous.

Comment: You have `public void Test(IB b)` defined as an *instance* member of the `Program` class, which means the only way it can be called is by creating a new instance of the class and *then* calling the method. Try defining both methods as `static` if you want to access them directly from the `static` method `Main`. *Then* you'll get a compiler error that the call is ambiguous.

Comment: @RufusL Indeed, I forgot the static that explain why the IA version was called. Thank you !

Comment: @Artz, I created both method static and I tried at my end but it is giving compile time error as : The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Program.Test(IA)' and 'Program.Test(IB)'. If I created explicitly of object IA or IB i.e. IA Ab = new AB();. Then working and calling corresponding method. Am I missing something?

Comment: @VikasGarg Nop, It was an error on my part. I forgot to add the static to Test(IB b) method sorry